# Creating a folder based on a portion of a file name

Tags: bash, scripts

I have several files named such:

```
KILN_SDUS51_N0SILN_201203020003
KILN_SDUS51_N0QILN_201203020003
KILN_SDUS51_N0RILN_201203020003
```

I need to file all of them into folders based on the three characters between `_` and `ILN` (i.e. `N0S`,`N0Q`,`N0R`).

I have been trying to write a bash script to do this but most similar examples I have found deal with using the f% parameter, which does not seem applicable in this case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
for file in ./*_???ILN*; do
    dir=${file%ILN*}
    dir=${dir##*_}
    mkdir -p "./$dir" &&
    mv -iv "$file" "./$dir"
done
```

See [FAQ 100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for more on string manipulations in bash.

Comment: Phew, that would have taken a while by hand, thanks for that link, it looks like my understanding was a little off!

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil

dr = sys.argv[1]; files = os.listdir(dr)
for f in [f for f in files if os.path.isfile(dr+"/"+f)]:
    folder = dr+"/"+f.split("_")[2].replace("ILN", "")
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        os.makedirs(folder)
    shutil.move(dr+"/"+f, folder+"/"+f)
```

Copy it into an empty file
Run it by:

```
python3 <script> <directory>
```

This will create the (sub)folder(s) if necessary, move the files into the folder(s)

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ./KILN_SDUS51_*; do
    dir="$(grep -Po "^.*_.*_\K.*(?=ILN)" <<<"$file")"
    mkdir "$dir" && mv "$file" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to explain your action? why my answer seems not correct to you? Its a very bad practice to give a downvote and then just leave....